# Is it possible to encapsulate event logic to avoid duplicate code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say when a checkbox is checked/unchecked, I want specific behavior to occur.

Now if there are multiple points in my code where I set a checkbox as checked/unchecked, I have to run through the same logic ever time.

What is a way I can encapsulate the logic that occurs when a checkbox is checked, and just re-use that logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you're currently binding click event handlers like this:

```
$('some-selector').click(function (event)
{
    // do fancy stuff here
});
```

To encapsulate that logic, you just need to switch from using an anonymous function, to a function that you can reuse, like this:

```
function handleClicks(event)
{
    // do fancy stuff here
}

$('some-selector').click(handleClicks);
$('some-other-selector').click(handleClicks);
```

How's that?

---

I might also take a guess at the fact that the logic you're writing and rewriting is to wire a "check-all" sort of checkbox to a group of checkboxes. I wrote a jQuery plugin recently to handle exactly this sort of thing.

I never got around to uploading it properly to GitHub - [here's the gist](http://gist.github.com/593720) of it. Let me know if you'd like to actually use it, and I can explain its usage - it's pretty darn simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just extending what 'Bears will eat you' said about using non-anonymous functions, you should all so integrate your own function library to jquery:

Create your functions like so

```
$.fn.handleClicks = function (){
    $(this).click(function(event){
        alert('Click');
        return false
    })
}
```

Then you can use them like so, makes things a little more neater and a little lesser code. IMO;

```
$('a').handleClicks();    ​
```

Comment: -1 You shouldn't be adding your own application specific code to the jQuery object.  It also has the disadvantage over the named function that you recreate the function every time you add the handler.  `this` inside a jQuery plugin refers to a jQuery object so you don't need to do `$(this)`.